# Why is C++11 constexpr so restrictive?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, language-design

As you probably know, C++11 introduces the `constexpr` keyword.

> C++11 introduced the keyword constexpr, which allows the user to
>   guarantee that a function or object constructor is a compile-time
>   constant.
>   [...]
>   This allows the compiler to understand, and verify, that [function name] is a
>   compile-time constant.

My question is why are there such strict restrictions on form of the functions that can be declared. I understand desire to guarantee that function is pure, but consider this:

> The use of constexpr on a function imposes some limitations on what
>   that function can do. First, the function must have a non-void return
>   type. Second, the function body cannot declare variables or define new
>   types. Third, the body may only contain declarations, null statements
>   and a single return statement. There must exist argument values such
>   that, after argument substitution, the expression in the return
>   statement produces a constant expression.

That means that this pure function is illegal:

```
constexpr int maybeInCppC1Y(int a, int b)
{
    if (a>0)
        return a+b;
    else
        return a-b;
  //can be written as   return  (a>0) ? (a+b):(a-b); but that isnt the point
}
```

Also you cant define local variables... :( 
So I'm wondering is this a design decision, or do compilers suck when it comes to proving function a is pure?

Comment: Many years later, in c++14, I think it is compilable now.  (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e84489e166f931b7)   or do I misunderstand something?  Is it undefined behavior?

Comment: c++14 relaxed rules for constexpr, but this question is about C++11

Comment: True, the answers and pretext apply to c++11, but even today, this is the first result when searching for "c++ constexpr unroll for". Future searcher, please note that **modern c++ does allow a for loop within a constexpr function/constructor**.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason you'd need to write statements instead of expressions is that you want to take advantage of the additional capabilities of statements, particularly the ability to loop. But to be useful, that would require the ability to declare variables (also banned).

If you combine a facility for looping, with mutable variables, with logical branching (as in `if` statements) then you have the ability to create infinite loops. It is not possible to determine if such a loop will ever terminate ([the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). Thus some sources would cause the compiler to hang.

By using recursive pure functions it is possible to cause infinite recursion, which can be shown to be equivalently powerful to the looping capabilities described above. However, C++ already has that problem at compile time - it occurs with template expansion - and so compilers already have to have a switch for "template stack depth" so they know when to give up.

So the restrictions seem designed to ensure that this problem (of determining if a C++ compilation will ever finish) doesn't get any thornier than it already is.

Comment: The "side effects" explanation seems a lot more likely to me, but does anyone really know the rationale behind, rather then guessing it?

Comment: `The reason you'd need to write statements [is]... the ability to loop.`  I disagree, I want `if`/`else` and local `const` objects for code readability, neither of which (should) add _any_ issues for compilers.

Comment: Sources which cause the compiler to hang should be considered invalid by definition. The compiler may or may not choose to try to detect this. This does not mean that it is impossible to compile this entire class of source code. This has nothing to do with the halting problem. C++14 does allow loops in constexpr functions.

Comment: "Thus some sources would cause the compiler to hang." This is a made-up problem. Real world template expansions cause compilers to hang routinely because modern C++ compilers have to implement a compile-time **functional** language interpreter and that's much harder than an **imperative** language interpreter. In real life, this is never a problem: your compile-time program hangs -> you've got a bug. What's the big deal.

Comment: @KubaOber how does the compiler detect the problem? The purpose of a compiler is to tell you there's a problem, not sit there spinning until you get bored and intervene manually.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker When your program does that runtime, it's on you to detect it. Compile time isn't any different. For example, LISP macros let you run arbitrary code at compile time, and LISP had this capability for what - 2 decades now? You can code in imperative, functional, declarative or any other style supported by LISP. It's all put to good use. C++ is deficient in that area, speaking in practical terms.

Comment: C++ is deficient in a lot of ways IMO. But on this topic, the point of static type checking is that it is different from executing a program to find out if it works. It's like the difference between experimental science (running code) and mathematical proof (compiling). If compilation becomes Turing complete, it gains power and loses simplicity.

Answer (score 29):

The rules for `constexpr` functions are designed such that it's *impossible* to write a `constexpr` function that has any side-effects.

By requiring `constexpr` to have no side-effects it becomes impossible for a user to determine where/when it was actually evaluated. This is important since `constexpr` functions are allowed to happen at both compile time and run time at the discretion of the compiler.

If side-effects were allowed then there would need to be some rules about the order in which they would be observed. That would be incredibly difficult to define - even harder than the `static` initialisation order problem.

A relatively simple set of rules for guaranteeing these functions to be side-effect free is to require that they be just a single expression (with a few extra restrictions on top of that). This sounds limiting initially and rules out the if statement as you noted. Whilst that particular case would have no side-effects it would have introduced extra complexity into the rules and given that you can write the same things using the ternary operator or recursively it's not really a huge deal.

[n2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf) is the paper that proposed the `constexpr` addition in C++. It discusses the rational for the design - the relevant quote seems to be this one from a discussion on destructors, but relevant generally:

> The reason is that a constant-expression is intended to be evaluated by the compiler
>   at translation time just like any other literal of built-in type; in particular no
>   observable side-effect is permitted.

Interestingly the paper also mentions that a previous proposal suggested the the compiler figured out automatically which functions were `constexpr` without the new keyword, but this was found to be unworkably complex, which seems to support my suggestion that the rules were designed to be simple.

(I suspect there will be other quotes in the references cited in the paper, but this covers the key point of my argument about the no side-effects)

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be that hard to determine `constexpr` functions, given that they have to be defined in the TU before they are used.  If all variables referenced are `const`, and all functions called are already `constexpr`, it's `constexpr`.  Otherwise, it's not `constexpr`.  I think the halting problem is the bigger concern.

Comment: Also the paper quoted doesn't mention that it was unworkably complex, but rather, a keyword clarified programmer intention, for meaningful diagnostics.

Comment: @mooingduck - the report did also say that the older rules are too complex and were the source of several defect reports. There's two ways you could write such rules: 1) anything goes, except a specific list or 2) only things on this list are permitted. My understanding is that the standard took the latter approach - define a list of rules that is usable but as small as possible. This is the result. It avoids complex edge cases and unambiguously lists what is allowed.

Comment: I didn't find the paragraph, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  I'll take your word on it.

Comment: Your opening sentence is incorrect. constexpr functions are allowed to have side-effects. However, there must exist arguments for which they do not. This is legal:

    int arbitaryEffect();
    constexpr int f(bool b) { return b ? 0 : arbitraryEffect(); }

Answer (score 13):

Actually the C++ standardization committee is thinking about removing several of these constraints for c++14. See the following working document http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html

Answer (score 3):

The restrictions could certainly be lifted quite a bit without enabling code which cannot be executed during compile time, or which cannot be proven to always halt. However I guess it wasn't done because

- it would complicate the compiler for minimal gain. C++ compilers are quite complex as is
- specifying exactly how much is allowed without violating the restrictions above would have been time consuming, and given that desired features have been postponed in order to get the standard out of the door, there probably was little incentive to add more work (and further delay of the standard) for little gain
- some of the restrictions would have been either rather arbitrary or rather complicated (especially on loops, given that C++ doesn't have the concept of a native incrementing for loop, but both the end condition and the increment code have to be explicitly specified in the for statement, making it possible to use arbitrary expressions for them)

Of course, only a member of the standards committee could give an authoritative answer whether my assumptions are correct.

Comment: `constexpr` functions are allowed to be recursive, so there is no guarantee they always halt. Implementations are allowed and intended to give up evaluating them after some recursion depth is reached (the standard suggests a minimum of 512).

Comment: @RichardSmith: While it is easy to put a limit on recursion, I don't think it's as easy to put a meaningful limit on mostly unrestricted evaluation.

Answer (score -4):

I think constexpr is just for const objects. I mean; you can now have static const objects like `String::empty_string` constructs statically(without hacking!). This may reduce time before 'main' called. And static const objects may have functions like `.length(), operator==,...` so this is why 'expr' is needed. In 'C' you can create static constant structs like below:

```
static const Foos foo = { .a = 1, .b = 2, };
```

Linux kernel has tons of this type classes. In c++ you could do this now with constexpr.

note: I dunno but code below should not be accepted so like if version:

```
constexpr int maybeInCppC1Y(int a, int b) { return (a > 0) ? (a + b) : (a - b); }
```