# Am I right with my assertions below?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, constexpr

In section 10.4.3 of his new book "TCPL", B. Stroustrup writes:

> A sufficiently simple user-defined type can be used in a constant
>   expression. For example:
>
> ```
> struct Point {
>     int x,y,z;
>     constexpr Point up(int d) { return {x,y,z+d}; }
>     constexpr Point move(int dx, int dy) { return {x+dx,y+dy}; }
> // ...
> };
> ```
>
> A class with a constexpr constructor is called a literal type. To be
>   simple enough to be constexpr, a constructor must have an empty body
>   and all members must be initialized by potentially constant
>   expressions. For example:
>
> constexpr Point origo {0,0};

This seems confusing to me for the following reasons:

- `struct Point` has no user defined constructor, nor its implicit default constructor is constexpr.
- `constexpr Point origo {0,0};` compiles because of paragraph 7.1.5/9 in the Standard (N3337), concerning the use of `constexpr` in object declarations and paragraph 8.5.1/7, concerning aggregates initialization. It has nothing to do with a constexpr constructor.

Comment: *"nor its implicit default constructor is constexpr*" Why shouldn't the implicitly-declared (&defined) default ctor be `constexpr`?

Comment: I agree with your second point: There's no constructor call in the aggregate-initialization `Point{0,0}`.

Comment: @dyp `Why shouldn't the implicitly-declared (&defined) default ctor be constexpr?`  Members `x`, `y` and `z` are not initialized.

Comment: Agree with both points now :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement of a user-defined constructor. The text says "user-defined type", which is true, and "constructor must have an empty body", which is true (default constructor is equivalent to one with an empty body).

Also `constexpr` is used to indicate that the result is a compile-time constant. It doesn't allow/disallow any particular syntax on functions, it just allows the compiler to verify at compile-time that a constant value is being returned as expected. The `constexpr` on the functions and declaration indicate only that the functions are returning a compile-time constant.

Edit: Oh, also, I think you might be linking a few independent statements in that quote. The first sentence and code snippet is illustrating how the user-defined type `Point` can be used as a return value for a `constexpr` function. The second bit is illustrating that `Point` can be used as a `constexpr` variable because its constructor is empty; the `{0,0}` syntax itself isn't specifically related to `constexpr` *constructors* but it satisfies the requirements for `constexpr` variables where "a constructor must have an empty body and all members must be initialized by potentially constant expressions". See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for a good overview of the variable/function/constructor terminology used with `constexpr`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the fact that the expression `constexpr Point origo {0,0};` compiles, has nothing to do with a constexpr constructor.

Comment: Actually, [`constexpr` puts significant limits on what can be in a function.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308812/why-is-c11-constexpr-so-restrictive)

Comment: @MikeDeSimone [to be considerably relaxed in C++14](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html)

Comment: I clarified some poorly stated points in my answer, sorry about that.